# gitlab letsencrypt http_authorization error

Tags: git, gitlab, lets-encrypt, acme

I've recently installed Gitlab CE on my Ubuntu server. My desired domain for running Gitlab is https://git.mydomain.com (This is a sample URL), so I prefered to use Lets Encrypt to enable SSL on the server.
At the end of installation, I received this error:

```
Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

letsencrypt_certificate[git.mydomain.com] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 5) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::Malformed: acme_certificate[staging] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb line 25) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::Malformed: Method not allowed
```

I've read many pages to find the solution, but none of them were not useful. May you help me to activate SSL on this Gitlab instance please?

Comment: If you are using a 12.2.x version of GitLab, you should see an update in the next few days with a fix. See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a problem which would be limited to your case.

A recent Dec. 2019 [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 38255](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/38255) (now [`gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab` issue 4900](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/4900) describes the same issue, for a *lot* of people.

> For others who may face the same problem, you should comment out all the block mentioned by @Azylog , including the acme_certificate 'staging' and end lines
>
> But it's a serious lack of conformity to the Let's Encrypt announcements. If method is not changed to POST-as-GET before November 1st, 2020, even the production certificate won't be issued and this workaround won't be any use.

This is related to [ACME v2 - Scheduled deprecation of unauthenticated resource GETs](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-scheduled-deprecation-of-unauthenticated-resource-gets/74380/4), active from yesterday.

> After Dec 4th, unauthenticated `HTTP GET` requests to ACME v2 resource URLs will return HTTP status code of 405 “`method not allowed`” and a body containing a JSON problem with type “`urn:ietf:params:acme:error:malformed`”.
>
> `POST-as-GET` requests authenticated by a signature from an account other than the creating account will return an HTTP status code of 403 “forbidden” and a body containing a JSON problem with type “`urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized`”.

Note: [**`unixcharles/acme-client`**](https://github.com/unixcharles/acme-client/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#205) 2.0.5 will use `POST-as-GET`, which should fix this issue.
The [merge request 3782](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/merge_requests/3782) shows the next version 12.6 of GitLab Omnibus will use acme-client 2.0.5.
[This will be backported](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/4900#note_257737158) into the next releases of 12.2.x through 12.5.x

---

Current workaround, proposed by  [Ahmed Mo7eb :: أحمد محب](https://gitlab.com/ahmed.moheb.am):

> 1. delete old certificate from ssl folder
> 2. install Cerbot "manually" (#`sudo certbot certonly -a manual`) &
>      (You must make port 80 and 443 available in firewall)
> 3. write your Domain name in order
> 4. go to: `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/www/.well-known/acme-challenge/`
>      "Create file with the name that appeared"
> 5. press Enter
> 6. Congratulation!

---

[Update January 2020](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/4900#note_266847736): this is supposed to work with GitLab 12.6.2.
No need to patch `certificated.rb` anymore.

The [Mohammad Saberi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789090/mohammad-saberi) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239820/gitlab-letsencrypt-http-authorization-error/59242739?noredirect=1#comment105653666_59242739) (January 15th, more than a month later):

> Finally, I could activate LetsEncrypt SSL on Gitlab 12.6.4, but with disabling staging part of `certificate.rb`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer you provided.  Azylog's answer did not solved the problem, but regarding to your note, it seems I have to wait for the next release of Gitlab

Comment: @MohammadSaberi Or simply the next GitLab minor update: you don't have to wait for the next 22nd of this month.

Comment: I updated Gitlab to 12.5.4, but the problem still exists and I got that error again while enabling https on the URL

Comment: @MohammadSaberi 12.5.4 was part of a critical security release batch (https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/12/10/critical-security-release-gitlab-12-5-4-released/) which did not yet include the backport I mention in the answer. Said backport was announced yesterday: I suspect we need to wait a few more days before the actual release.

Comment: you are right. It was my mistake... Thanks for replying my comments and question

Comment: After waiting for an official an minor update, and updating to version 12.6.0, the previous problem still exists!
`(letsencrypt::http_authorization line 5) had an error: RuntimeError: acme_certificate[staging] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb line 25)`

Comment: @MohammadSaberi OK, you might want to update the issue ticket, and let them know.

Comment: @MohammadSaberi This is supposed to be fixed with GitLab 12.6.2 (January 2020).

Comment: finally, I could activate LetsEncrypt SSL on Gitlab 12.6.4, but with disabling staging part of `certificate.rb`

Comment: @MohammadSaberi Thank you for this feedback.I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 6):

A workaround is described in [gitlab-issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/4900#note_257737158):

Modify

> /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb

and comment out the staging part (line 25 to 38).

Worked for me (tm).

Comment: This worked for me. I was having problem running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, it was throwing error with letsencrypt http_authorization error. commenting out the staging part reconfigured it and I was able to upgrade gitlab-ce packages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem which we faced is different but the error is same.

(In my case, letsencrypt certificate was expired and renew flow is broken for GitLab 12.2.5-ee.0.)

What we did is...

- Upgrade to the latest version of Gitlab (Current stable version is: 12.7.6-ee.0 )
- Edit the gitlab.rb
- Remove the old certificates
- Reconfigure the GitLab server

I wrote the detailed steps here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/4900#note_292031191